# Painting aligment and texture bleeding even with margin turned on

Tags: texture-painting

How can I avoid bleed like this? It's only appearing when I paint in 3D space, on 2D there's no such a problem. I used margin option with different sizes; UV island are separated with wide margin.
Also, is there in Blender an option like in Substance Painter, called "Aligment" with aligment like UV, Tangent, Camera?

[image: Margin bleed]

Comment: It looks like you've been painting with a different color that crossed the seams.  What is adjacent to this in the 3D view?  If you want a hard border, use a hard brush and be careful, use masking, or separate islands to different objects temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

In the Options Tab in Texture Paint mode you can set the bleed to 0; I do that here and get something like you might be looking for. 
[image: bleed at 0]